# CS-Cart user login with rest api

Tags: php, rest, cs-cart

I am trying to login user with CS-Cart Rest API.

I want to access to log in the user into Android Mobile Application. I have done the registration part but the login part is not working.

According to CS-Cart Documentation:

password - The value of this field is the md5 hash of the user password. Used only when creating and updating a user.

So, I can use the password field only to create or update the user, but i want to login. I tried with the database, but it won't work either, they use multiple encryption md5 with salt.

Function used by CS CART FOr the website:

```
$password = '';

if (strlen($user_data['password']) == 32) {
    $password = $user_data['password'];
} else {
    if (!isset($user_data['salt']) || empty($user_data['salt'])) {
        $password = md5($user_data['password']);
    } else {
        $password = fn_generate_salted_password($user_data['password'], $user_data['salt']);
    }
}

return $password;
```

Now I want to know if I can access and validate the user with the REST API, if not how can I validate the user, if email and password matches, then it will be logged in on my Android Application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not an expert, dont even know about cs Cart. But looking at the CS CART documentation available at https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/auth.html#url , i can say, that cs cart authentication takes only email address as parameter for authentication.

Comment: But I need a password field to verify the user and then logged in. The documentation is not helpful at all.

Comment: In that case what i would recommend is, you should have your own login system, and once your login passes, then you can call the CS CART endpoint. you can do this, either by integrating Database or a simple file storage. I believe you need to do on database.

Comment: I have access to the database but the problem is I can't get the hashing they are using, as I attached the Function above, I tried to decrypt md5 hash but it shows different value

Comment: i didn't quite get you. is it your own database or you are trying to call from CS CART API?

Comment: By re-reading your question and CS CART documentation, you are not given any end point for authentication using email and password. the only endpoint they have is email parameter and redirect link. Thats why, i have suggested you to do a middleware server, where you will manage your own user details and create login system.

Comment: @PharsaThapa What's the best way to do it, I checked the Database where the users are stored, but I am not understanding which decryption is used for the password.

Comment: Can i use firebase for authentication? How will i make sure the user_id, email and password will be same on the main database and firebase?

Comment: It is not necessarily important that you need to know their encryption system. Would you say your user that you are using an specific hashing function?? Regarding, firebase, i guess you can use it. you will supply only the plain password, to both systems and the systems will do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per their REST API documentation, you need to use the user API key alongwith their email to list users. You need to enable the api access and generate the api key from the admin panel. Customers->Administrators-> user account.

please follow the link https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/users.html to know more...

password Field:     The value of this field is md5 hash of user password. Used only when creating and updating a user

Comment: Ravi is correct. I recently used the rest API and the Authentication section states the use of the API key in combination with the email. https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/index.html#authentication